# Why doesn't the extension for the filename get saved for my XLS downloads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I'm trying to export to an XLS file. The file is being saved but without an extension. When I download the file I need to manually add ".xls" to specify it's an Excel file.

Here is my code from my view:

```
  <%= link_to("Export","http://localhost:3000/policy_management/policy/generate_print_ejecutive/generate_print_ejecutive_comercial.xls") %>

  <%= link_to "Export", :controller=>"policy_management/policy",:action=>"generate_print_ejecutive_comercial" ,:format=>"xls",:search => params[:search],:page => params[:page],:filename=>"aaa.xls" %>
```

Here is my code from my controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.xls { render  :partial=>"report_by_ejecutive",:filename=>"aaa.xls"}
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `render` method does not do anything with the `:filename` option passed to it. However `send_data` does accept `filename` option but it needs to have the file as string. So  using `render_to_string` to convert the partial to a string.

```
format.xls { send_data render_to_string(:partial=>"report_by_ejecutive"), :filename => "aaa.xls" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your Mime-Type? In `/config/initializers/mime_types.rb` add `Mime::Type.register "application/xls", :xls` then restart the server.

In particular, see this Railscasts episode: http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast

Also, you might want to use `send_data` (that allows you to set the file name too): http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data

Comment: i did it but it still happen

Comment: Even using `send_data`?

Comment: it is really strange i don't have idea that why is not working? did you check my code?

Comment: @charlie added an answer with send_data